# Ubuntu 20.04 crashes when unplugging HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, crash

My Ubuntu system crashes whenever I disconnect a second monitor: the laptop screen turns black, all I can do is a hard reboot. It used to happen once in a while with 18.04, but now I've updated to 20.04 and it seems to always happen.

```
$ sudo lshw -class display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: UHD Graphics 620
       fabricant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration : driver=i915 latency=0
       ressources : irq:139 mémoire:ee000000-eeffffff mémoire:d0000000-dfffffff portE/S:f000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

It may or may not be related: the system also crashes more often than not when it goes to different power saving modes (which I've learnt to avoid by now)... If there's a solution for both problems together that'd be welcome :)

**Edit:** <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>..<kbd>F7</kbd> keys and sysrq keys do nothing (maybe I missed one, if there's one that should absolutely work in all contexts, let me know).
On the positive side, the crash does **not happen** when I'm playing music through *rhythmbox*. If it's any use, the song that was playing when I tried was "Come" by Jain (at this point I've just abandoned all assumptions of possible causality).

**Re-edit:** even after rebooting I don't get the crash anymore, and turning on rhythmbox was the only difference it seems... so it's kind of problem solved, thank you *Jain*, but maybe I'm just back to "random crashes" as before.

Comment: hard reboot?  can't you switch to text terminal & explore/kill to fix?  does sysrq keys direct to kernel not allow clean reboot?  what do you mean by hard reboot?  If it's a crash as you say, what was the package impacted by the crash (ie. what was in /var/crash/? as even the filename(s) of the crash report alone provide valuable details in resolving or working around issue, even if you ignore contents of file(s))

Comment: @guiverc thanks for your questions, maybe "crash" isn't the right word: I just have a  black screen, nothing I can do with it. By hard reboot I mean long press the power button, then restart. I don't know how to switch to terminal, keys ctrl+alt+f1..do nothing. Nothing in /var/crash/  ...:(

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F2..F7 will switch you to term, Ctrl+Alt+F1 will switch you to GUI (where you were already; though keys can be changed and vary on kernel anyway; F7 used to be GUI on older kernels).. SysRq keys/commands allow you to direct kernel directly (bypassing any GUI or terminal allowing safe reboots (sync buffers to disk, close file-systems etc inc. reboot, turn off etc; safe & extremely quick).  Your GUI was hanging it sounds like (crash means there would be a crash file, or kernel panic on screen; and keyboard won't respond to correct keys you didn't try it appears)

Comment: @guiverc Nothing with ctrl+alt+F2..F7 either (btw it's still ctrl alt F7 for GUI for me, not F1) . I tried a bunch of SysRq keys as well: nothing (interestingly, I tried some also when the system was live, but mostly nothing happened, except at some  point it shut down the system and now I don't have windows in my dual boot anymore...)

Comment: What SysRq keys did you use?  REISUB is the usual start with each letter being a command (the final B = boot, but importantly X=kill gui, E=terminal processors, I=kill, S=sync to write any memory buffers not on disk to disk, U=umount)  using the wrong keys can do harm (O=off, which I'd only use other keys (REISU usually for example to ensure to protect system). SysRq gives commands to the kernel which can prevent harm but also may do harm if used wrongly.

Comment: I tried REISUB first (as per wikipedia), nothing, then some random ones when I didn't get any effect: iso yes it's probably the O that stopped it. Anyway the dual boot is not a big deal (esc. on startup to see grub, esc.again for the terminal, exit and then I get windows when I need it...)

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same symptoms (desktop frozen when disconnected from monitors, but keyboard lights and ssh to it still worked), but likely a different root cause. Nevertheless, I'm sharing my outcome here.

I have a Dell XPS 9500 running Ubuntu 20.04 with NVIDIA driver 470.82. My setup was the laptop connected to a docking station (inconsequential, I think) and the docking station connected to two monitors - one with HDMI and the second with a DisplayPort cable. I had the DisplayLink drivers installed. Emphasis on *had*. I ended up uninstalling the DisplayLink driver and instead connecting the second monitor with HDMI. I haven't had this problem since.

DisplayLink seems to have acknowledged some issues with Ubuntu freezing, although it doesn't sound like *exactly* the same situation.
https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/641668-known-issues-with-displaylink-ubuntu-support

There may be workarounds, but I didn't have time for that, so I just uninstalled the DisplayLink driver.

I guess this likely wasn't your cause, as you only mention HDMI, but hopefully this helps someone out.

Answer (score 1):

i had same problems as you. My scenario:

- Two monitors.
- If the laptop suspends, black screen and never return to desktop. But fans works, and keyboard lights too. Only works a hard reset.
- No Ctrl+Alt+F(whatever) works!!
- If i unplugged the second hmdi, same result: black screen.
- The pc still working, because i can access by ssh session.
- Intel 620 as graphics card.

The solution i have found, it's use wayland, and not XOrg. All working, with my screens, but some other problems with electron apps (like Teams).

Still i'm working in find a better solution.